# Upload a file using Spring MVC and Angular JS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am trying to upload a csv file from JSp to controller. I can able to upload the file sucessfully but I am getting the Response '**syntax error:unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON parse using angular js**'. I need to read the data from a csv file and display it in jsp page. When i am trying to upload I am getting issue with response.

JSP CODE:

```
<form action="robiiBiaascsvUpload/fileuploadinfo" id="FileUploadForm"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ng-controller="fileUploadController"> 
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" id="uploadFile">
   <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="middle">Upload File:</td><br/>
            <td align="left" valign="middle">
            <input name="file2" id="file2" type="file" file-model="file2"/><br/>
            </td>
             <td><input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="uploadFormData();"></td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var app = angular.module('formSubmit', []);


    app.controller('fileUploadController',function($scope,$http){

        $scope.uploadFormData=function()
        {
            // headers: {'Content-Type': false},
            // file2.files[0]
            //alert(file2.files[0].name);
            var oMyForm = new FormData();
            oMyForm.append("file",file2.files[0]);
             $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'uploadFile',
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
                data: oMyForm,
                transformRequest: function(response, headersGetterFunction) {
                     headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
                    //alert(response);
                     //return response;


                        return response;
                 },headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
             }).success(function(data, headers) {   
                    alert(data);
                 })
                 .error(function(data, headers)
                         {
                        alert("Exception"+data);
                         });


        }

    });
```

Spring mvc Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile")
    public @ResponseBody String upLoadFile(HttpServletRequest request,
             @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) {
        StringBuilder result=null;
        ModelMap map=new ModelMap();
        try 
        {

            System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());

            System.out.println(file.getBytes());
            InputStream in=file.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
                result.append('\n');
            }
            map.addAttribute("status", "success");
            map.addAttribute("list", result.toString());
            System.out.println(result.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

          return "Success";
    }
```

Please let me know where i went Wrong.

Comment: Please could you explain where you see the response. Does it come from the commented out `alert(response)`

Comment: Actually, Its going into Error Block, Response In transformRequest block I am getting OBJECTFORMDATA

Comment: Then I suspect that the client is seeing the "Success" string without any JSON formatting. How about adding `@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}) ` as an annotation on the mthod

Comment: I am not using Spring Rest API. I am using only Pure Spring MVC

Comment: I got the output . thanks JR. Issue is in Controller class I need to send response through JSONOBject